# Microsoft Access support for checkbox column against linked Oracle table

Tags: oracle, ms-access, checkbox, boolean, linked-tables

I have an access file that is using a linked Oracle table.

When I open the linked table in Access, I want to have a column display as a checkbox, like the `YES`/`NO` Access datatype does.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a form as is more proper for editing a table?

Comment: @Remou This is part of a large Access application that has pathways directly to the tables.  We are trying to phase out the Access application, the first step being moving the local tables to be linked Oracle tables.  We are not looking to spend any additional time adding new features to the Access application.

Comment: It would take 5 minutes at the most to create a datasheet form based on your table, and I reckon it is about your only hope of a checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're opposed to using a form with a check box control for the linked table, you can modify the linked table's `TableDef`.  Add a *DisplayControl* property to your numeric field with property value as 106 for a check box.

I ran the following example in the Immediate window.  `dbo_foo` is linked to a SQL Server table since I don't have Oracle available.  The field `a_number` is interpreted by Access as Long Integer (not Yes/No data type).

```vb
set db = currentdb
set fld = db.TableDefs("dbo_foo").Fields("a_number")
fld.Properties.Append fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", dbInteger, 106)
' verify property created with correct value ...
? fld.Properties("DisplayControl")
 106
```

If for some reason your target field already has a different *DisplayControl* value set, just change that value (instead of `.Append` with `.CreateProperty`).

```vb
fld.Properties("DisplayControl") = 106
```

After setting the property, my `a_number` field is displayed as a check box when `dbo_foo` is opened in Datasheet View.  See whether that approach gives you what you want with your Oracle table.

Comment: Thank you for your response this seems like the direction I would like to go.  I don't fully understand the solution though.
How can I add a DisplayControl property to my numeric field?  Currently, the only place I know where to set the DisplayControl is under the Lookup tab for a given column.  How/where can I setup the DisplayControl programmatically?

Comment: I can refer to local Access tables with: set db = CurrentDb()
Do you know how I can refer to a linked table's db?

Comment: Perhaps you're not familiar with the Immediate window.  Open it with Ctrl+g.  Then type `set db = currentdb` and press Enter.  On the next line, type `set fld = db.TableDefs("YourLinkedTable").Fields("YourNumericField")` and press Enter.  On the third line, paste in the line from the answer which begins with `fld.Properties.Append` and press Enter.

Comment: You are correct I was not familiar with the Immediate window. I've been poking around in it all morning.  I followed your instructions and the number field on the linked table is now displaying as a checkbox.  Under the Lookup tab the field "Display Control" is set to 106. The change persists through closing and reopening the Access file. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, the situation is confusing from the user interface.  The Lookup tab's Display Control option will only allow you to choose from the values it offers.  And, if you type in 106, it will reject it.  However if you assign 106 via the field's DisplayControl property from the TableDef, Access will happily use it and display the field as a check box.

Comment: I agree it isn't very intuitive from the GUI but does exactly what I need.  I really appreciate your help on this.